# Quarkus and javax libraries

Tags: quarkus, jakarta-migration

I'm wondering if there is any technical reason behind the fact that Quarkus still relies on javax namespace instead of using the new jakarta namespace.

What confuses me more, is that many docs report the usage of Jakarta libraries (e.g. see here https://quarkiverse.github.io/quarkiverse-docs/quarkus-amazon-services/dev/amazon-dynamodb.html#_create_the_quarkusfruits_table) while the corresponding repository (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/blob/main/amazon-dynamodb-quickstart/src/main/java/org/acme/dynamodb/FruitAsyncService.java) shows that in reality, Jakarta libs are not available.

From Jakarta EE 9 was released in 2020, so I guess this should be a change widely embraced by major frameworks like Quarkus.

I ask this, because I'm importing third party libraries which are using Jakarta namespace and this brings a lot of confusion.

Maybe there is a way to switch to the new Jakarta namespace that I couldn't see yet. Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarkus 3 will use the jakarta namespace.

It should be released soon. Until then, folks are encouraged to test the Alpha versions we regularly publish l.

See https://quarkus.io/blog/road-to-quarkus-3/ for more details

Comment: Ok, so for now nothing to do.

Comment: You can use the alpha versions we publish.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on @geoand's answer, the reason Quarkus isn't *already* using the Jakarta namespace is that all of the components included in the Quarkus platform all need to be using `jakarta`. Otherwise it would be a mess! (You're  seeing this same mess in your own application, since some of your dependencies have moved and some haven't.) Some libraries included in Quarkus have been able to switch quicker than others, so the overall effort needs coordination. Since the switch from `javax` to `jakarta` is a breaking change, it's accompanied by a major version bump in Quarkus.

When looking at documentation, there's a bit of luck about which version a search engine will take you to, but then you can select which version's documentation to look at. That allows you to explore upcoming capability, and also make sure you're using the correct docs for the version you're using. For the main quarkus docs the latest nightly build's docs will be `main`, and then you can also select Quarkus releases. In the broader Quarkiverse, there's no universal versioning scheme, but there's a similar drop-down for version selection, in the top-right.

[image: a drop down showing dev and 1.x]